# Bootstrapping: Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument(s) (original)

Tags: r

I have a database of position estimates, and want to calculate monthly kernel utilization distributions. I can do this using the adehabitat package in R, but I would like to estimate 95%confidence intervals for these values using bootstrapping that samples from the database.
Today I've been experimenting with the boot package, but I am still fairly new to R and am needing some more expert help!
The main error message I'm getting is:

```
Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument(s) (original)
```

Here is a look at the file I've been using:

```
    head(all)
Num          Hourbin  COA_Lat   COA_Lon  POINT_X POINT_Y   month year    id
1 07/10/2010 15:00 48.56225 -53.89144 729339.9 5383461 October 2010 29912
2 07/10/2010 16:00 48.56254 -53.89121 729355.7 5383495 October 2010 29912
4 07/10/2010 18:00 48.56225 -53.89144 729339.7 5383461 October 2010 29912
5 07/10/2010 19:00 48.56225 -53.89144 729339.9 5383461 October 2010 29912
6 07/10/2010 20:00 48.56225 -53.89144 729339.8 5383461 October 2010 29912
7 07/10/2010 21:00 48.56225 -53.89144 729339.9 5383461 October 2010 29912
```

With columns 5 and 6 being the X and Y positions respectively. I subset this dataset for different months (ie getting files named "oct","nov",etc). I have tried setting up the kernelUD function in the adehabitat package to be a function that I can call up for bootstrapping, but have had no luck so far.

```
kUDoct<-function(i) kernel.area(oct[,5:6],oct[,10],kern="bivnorm",unin=c("m"),unout=c("km2"))
bootoct<-boot(oct,kUDoct,R=1000)
Error in statistic(data, original, ...) : unused argument(s) (original)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

M

Comment: What's `kernel.area`? Where's `all`? What does `oct` look like? Why doesn't `kUDoct` use index `i` in the body?

Answer (score 8):

Well, *a* problem that you're having is that you aren't using the `boot` function as the documentation direct you to. From `?boot` we see that the second argument, `statistic` is:

> A function which when applied to data returns a vector containing the
>   statistic(s) of interest. When sim = "parametric", the first argument
>   to statistic must be the data. For each replicate a simulated dataset
>   returned by ran.gen will be passed. In all other cases statistic must
>   take at least two arguments. The first argument passed will always be
>   the original data. The second will be a vector of indices, frequencies
>   or weights which define the bootstrap sample.

Note that this means your function should be defined to take *at least* two arguments. Your accepts only one (and then ignores it completely, oddly enough).

The idea is that you pass in your original data, and a vector of indicies. Then you calculate your statistic of interest by subsetting your original data using those indicies, which will constitute a "bootstrap sample".

So instead of this:

```
kUDoct<-function(i) kernel.area(oct[,5:6],oct[,10],kern="bivnorm",unin=c("m"),unout=c("km2"))
bootoct<-boot(oct,kUDoct,R=1000)
```

You'd probably want to do something more like this:

```
kUDoct<-function(dat,ind) kernel.area(dat[ind,5:6],dat[ind,10],kern="bivnorm",unin=c("m"),unout=c("km2"))
bootoct<-boot(oct,kUDoct,R=1000)
```

But I can't diagnose any other errors you may get, as your example isn't entirely reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I realised that I had only had one argument, so I have done something similar to your suggestion, which is running right now, so we'll see if it works!              kudoct<-function(data,indices){
  kUDoct<-kernel.area(oct[,5:6],oct[,10],kern="bivnorm",unin=c("m"),unout=c("km2"))
  return(summary(kUDoct))
}
bootoct<-boot(data=oct,statistic=kudoct,R=1000)

Comment: @user1195564 That won't work. Look carefully at my example, as well as the examples in `?boot`.

Comment: ah, yes I see where I am going wrong. I will format things as per your suggestion and give it a try. THANKS!

Comment: just tried it, and now I get the error:                          Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix

Comment: @user1195564 See the last sentence of my answer, as well as Roman's comment above.

Comment: Ok, would it help if I include a google doc of my file "oct"? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aus9Y05U85wwdDNSbEUyUnRUa1NYMWpLTDFyQTZ1YXc